# Matlab : decision tree shows invalid output values

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm making a decision tree using the classregtree(X,Y) function. I'm passing X as a matrix of size 70X9 (70 data objects, each having 9 attributes), and Y as a 70X1 matrix. Each one of my Y values is either 2 or 4. However, in the decision tree formed, it gives values of 2.5 or 3.5 for some of the leaf nodes.

Any ideas why this might be caused?

Comment: also, while we're on this topic, how does classregtree deal with missing attributes? I have some objects with missing attributes in my data set, and I have no idea which method matlab is using to deal with this. Does it remove such objects? Interpolates them? Uses surrogate splits?

Comment: Use `NaN` to represent missing values. CLASSREGTREE has an option `surrogate` to deal with missing values in the training phase. Just refer to the documentation of the functions in question... You can always preprocess your data by replacing the missing values with mean/mode, or perform any of the other imputation techniques

Comment: In my data, Ive put NaN for the missing values. Ive provided no other information regarding how to deal with the missing data to classregtree. So what is the default method that classregtree uses to deal with the NaN values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using classregtree in regression mode (which is the default mode). 
Change the mode to classification mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using [CLASSREGTREE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/classregtree.html) for classification:

```
%# load dataset
load fisheriris

%# split training/testing
cv = cvpartition(species, 'holdout',1/3);
trainIdx = cv.training;
testIdx = cv.test;

%# train
t = classregtree(meas(trainIdx,:), species(trainIdx), 'method','classification', ...
    'names',{'SL' 'SW' 'PL' 'PW'});

%# predict
pred = t.eval(meas(testIdx,:));

%# evaluate
cm = confusionmat(species(testIdx),pred)
acc = sum(diag(cm))./sum(testIdx)
```

The output (confusion matrix and accuracy):

```
cm =
    17     0     0
     0    13     3
     0     2    15
acc =
          0.9
```

[image: tree]

Now if your target class is encoded as numbers, the returned prediction will still be cell array of strings, so you have to convert them back to numbers:

```
%# load dataset
load fisheriris
[species,GN] = grp2idx(species);

%# ...

%# evaluate
cm = confusionmat(species(testIdx),str2double(pred))
acc = sum(diag(cm))./sum(testIdx)
```

Note that classification will always return strings, so I think you might have mistakenly used the `method=regression` option, which performs [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) (numeric target) not [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning) (discrete target)